# java 1.6 32-bit min and max heap memory issue

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have the JRE v1.6 that is 32-bit installed. When I attempt to run a program as follows:

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m net.analysis.MyProg
```

I see the following message displayed:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine
```

As far as I know, the maximum heap allowed for a 32-bit JVM is 2 GB. On the computer running my code there is 131061 MB of physical memory (using Window's Task Manager, 128 GB of RAM).

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: AFAIK - The heap space needs to be contiguous.  Even they you might have enough free memory, it my be fragmented...

Comment: What version of windows are you using.  On many 32bit windows the limit is 3GB

Comment: WTF 128GB of RAM - envious

Comment: the server that is running the code is Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise 64-bit. Other specs of interests: Intel Xeon CPU X7560 @ 2.27GHz (4 processors, but task manager shows 16x4=32 cores).

Comment: If you are running a 32-bit windows application you are limited to what the windows XP emulation will do.  It doesn't matter how much memory you have, 32-bit windows limits you to 1.2 - 1.4 GB of heap.  You really should be using a 64-bit JVM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, the limit is most likely the 32 bit architecture and the way that Windows is apportioning the virtual address space.

According to the [Oracle JVM FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit), you can only expect to get 1.4Gb to 1.6Gb on a 32bit JVM on Windows.

Comment: i think you are right. i tried the following: java -Xms1g -Xmx1536m net.analysis.MyProg and that works. so about 1.5Gb is the limit. thanks a lot.